# WindowsAzure Javascript Console in Production code

Tags: angular, azure

I would like to disable console from WindowsAzure, as it reveals the url. It is definitely a security breach.

Below is the console, which displays the azurewebsites.net url.
[image]

I have tried adding `<script>console.log = function(){}</script>` to my index.html It blocks my console but not the azurewebsites.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is the browser's behavior, we don't have much control on it. And I don't think it's a good idea to overwrite `console.log` function for security because we are still able to trace the HTTP request in the **Network** panel.

Since you are using Azure Mobile App with Easy Table, I would suggest you set up the authentication for your app and change the table's permissions to protect your API.

[image]

For more information, please refer to [this blog post](https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/11/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-6-personal-tables/).